# Problems with positioning slider under nav-bar css html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a nav-bar and slider using CSS and HTML however when I try to position the slider under the nav-bar the slider just disappears. I have been trying to fix this but I have constantly failed. So I am stuck at this part:

[image: my problem]

Is there a way I can place the slider under the nav-bar I have already tried `padding` however the slider just disappears.

Here is my project:

```js
var slidesWrapper = $('.cd-hero-slider');

//check if a .cd-hero-slider exists in the DOM
if (slidesWrapper.length > 0) {

  var sliderNav = $('.cd-slider-nav');
  var slidesNumber = slidesWrapper.children('li').length;
  var visibleSlidePosition = 0;
  var autoPlayId;
  var autoPlayDelay = 5000;

  // autoplay slider
  setAutoplay(slidesWrapper, slidesNumber, autoPlayDelay);

  // change visible slide
  sliderNav.on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var selectedItem = $(this);

    if (!selectedItem.hasClass('selected')) {

      // if it's not already selected
      var selectedPosition = selectedItem.index();
      var activePosition = slidesWrapper.find('li.selected').index();

      if (activePosition < selectedPosition) {
        nextSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, selectedPosition);
      } else {
        prevSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, selectedPosition);
      }

      //this is used for the autoplay
      visibleSlidePosition = selectedPosition;

      updateSliderNavigation(sliderNav, selectedPosition);
      setAutoplay(slidesWrapper, slidesNumber, autoPlayDelay);
    }
  });
}

function nextSlide(visibleSlide, container, pagination, n) {
  visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
    visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
  });

  container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-right').prevAll().addClass('move-left');
}

function prevSlide(visibleSlide, container, pagination, n) {
  visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
    visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
  });

  container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-left').removeClass('move-left').nextAll().removeClass('move-left');
}

function updateSliderNavigation(pagination, n) {
  var navigationDot = pagination.find('.selected');
  navigationDot.removeClass('selected');
  pagination.find('a').eq(n).addClass('selected');
}

// autoplay
function setAutoplay(wrapper, length, delay) {
  if (wrapper.hasClass('autoplay')) {
    clearInterval(autoPlayId);
    autoPlayId = window.setInterval(function() {
      autoplaySlider(length)
    }, delay);
  }
}

function autoplaySlider(length) {
  if (visibleSlidePosition < length - 1) {
    nextSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition + 1);
    visibleSlidePosition += 1;
  } else {
    prevSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, 0);
    visibleSlidePosition = 0;
  }
  updateSliderNavigation(sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition);
}
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #2c343b;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

a {
  color: #d44457;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.cd-hero {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}

.cd-hero-slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cd-hero-slider li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.cd-hero-slider li.selected {
  /* this is the visible slide */
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.cd-hero-slider li.move-left {
  /* slide hidden on the left */
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected {
  /* the is-moving class is assigned to the slide which is moving outside the viewport */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}


/* --------------------------------

Single slide style

-------------------------------- */

.cd-hero-slider li {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
  width: 45%;
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width:first-of-type {
  left: 5%;
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width:nth-of-type(2) {
  right: 5%;
  left: auto;
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-content {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  transform: translateY(-52%) !important;
  padding: 0 50px;
}


/*
    animations & transitions
*/

.cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(40px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(40px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(40px);
  -o-transform: translateX(40px);
  transform: translateX(40px);
}

.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-half-width {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-40px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-40px);
  transform: translateX(-40px);
}

.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-half-width {
  /* this is the visible slide */
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.cd-hero-slider .is-moving .cd-half-width {
  /* this is the slide moving outside the viewport
    wait for the end of the transition on the <li> parent before set opacity to 0 and translate to 40px/-40px */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0s 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -moz-transform 0s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, transform 0s 0.5s;
}

.cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-left .cd-half-width:nth-of-type(2),
.cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-right .cd-half-width:first-of-type {
  /* this is the selected slide - different animation if it's entering from left or right */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, transform 0.5s 0.2s;
}

.cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-left .cd-half-width:first-of-type,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-right .cd-half-width:nth-of-type(2) {
  /* this is the selected slide - different animation if it's entering from left or right */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, transform 0.5s 0.4s;
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width h1,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width h2,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width h3,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width h4,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width h5,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width h6,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width p,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width a,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width .button {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100px);
  -o-transform: translateX(100px);
  transform: translateX(100px);
}

.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width h1,
.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width h2,
.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width h3,
.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width h4,
.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width h5,
.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width h6,
.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width p,
.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width .button {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-100px);
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}

.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width h1,
.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width h2,
.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width h3,
.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width h4,
.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width h5,
.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width h6,
.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width p,
.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width .button {
  /* this is the visible slide */
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width h1,
.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width h2,
.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width h3,
.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width h4,
.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width h5,
.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width h6,
.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width p,
.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width .button {
  /* this is the slide moving outside the viewport
    wait for the end of the transition on the li parent before set opacity to 0 and translate to 100px/-100px */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0s 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -moz-transform 0s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, transform 0s 0.5s;
}


/* different timings for different elements */

.cd-hero-slider li.selected h1,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected h2,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected h3,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected h4,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected h5,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected h6 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, transform 0.5s 0.2s;
}

.cd-hero-slider li.selected p {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 0.3s, transform 0.5s 0.3s;
}

.cd-hero-slider li.selected .button,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected input[type="button"],
.cd-hero-slider li.selected button {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.4s, background-color 0.2s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.4s, background-color 0.2s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, transform 0.5s 0.4s, background-color 0.2s 0s;
}


/*
    slider navigation
*/

.cd-slider-nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
}

.cd-slider-nav nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.cd-slider-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.cd-slider-nav a.selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/* --------------------------------

Javascript disabled

-------------------------------- */

.no-js .cd-hero-slider li {
  display: none;
}

.no-js .cd-hero-slider li.selected {
  display: block;
}

.no-js .cd-slider-nav {
  display: none;
}

@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,500,900';
body {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.nav2 {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-out;
}

.banner {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}

.nav2 ul#menu {
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.nav2 .ul2 .li2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.nav-bar {
  /* Rectangle 1: */
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11), 0px 4px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------

/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/

.ul2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}


/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/

.li2 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: center;
}


/*Style for menu links*/

.li2 .a2 {
  display: block;
  min-width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2f3036;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*Hover state for top level links*/

.li2:hover .a2 {
  background: #19c589;
}


/*Style for dropdown links*/

.li2:hover .ul2 .a2 {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  color: #2f3036;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}


/*Hover state for dropdown links*/

.li2:hover .ul2 .a2:hover {
  background: #19c589;
  color: #fff;
}


/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

.li2 .ul2 {
  display: none;
}


/*Make dropdown links vertical*/

.li2 .ul2 .li2 {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}


/*Prevent text wrapping*/

.li2 .ul2 .li2 .a2 {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
}


/*Display the dropdown on hover*/

.ul2 .li2 .a2:hover+.hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
}


/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

.show-menu {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #19c589;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  display: none;
}


/*Hide checkbox*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}


/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#menu {
  display: block;
}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  .nav2 .ul2#menu {
    position: static;
    display: none;
  }
  /*Create vertical spacing*/
  .li2 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  .ul2 .li2,
  .li2 .a2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*Display 'show menu' link*/
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}

.hero-image {
  /* The image used */
  /* Set a specific height */
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  /* Position and center the image to scale nicely on all screens */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#menu {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>slick slider</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <nav class="nav2">
    <div class="banner animated"><img class="hero-image" src="https://picsum.photos/1080/200/?random"></div>
    <div class="nav-bar"> <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
      <ul id="menu" class="ul2">
        <li class="li2"><a href="#" class="a2">Home</a></li>
        <li class="li2">
          <a href="#" class="a2">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="li2">
          <a href="#" class="a2">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="li2"><a href="#" class="a2">News</a></li>
        <li class="li2"><a href="#" class="a2">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section class="cd-hero">

    <ul class="cd-hero-slider autoplay">

      <li class="selected" style="background-color:#3498db">
        <div class="cd-full-width">
          <div class="cd-content">
            <h2>slide content</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li style="background-color:#34495e">
        <div class="cd-half-width">
          <div class="cd-content">
            <h2>slide content</h2>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cd-half-width cd-img-container">
          <div class="cd-content">
            <h2>slide content</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li style="background-color:#e67e22">
        <div class="cd-half-width cd-img-container">
          <div class="cd-content">
            <h2>slide content</h2>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cd-half-width">
          <div class="cd-content">
            <h2>slide content</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li style="background-color:#2ecc71">
        <div class="cd-full-width">
          <div class="cd-content">
            <h2>slide content</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li style="background-color:#9b59b6">
        <div class="cd-full-width">
          <div class="cd-content">
            <h2>slide content</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem commodi corporis, dignissimos dolorem doloremque eveniet explicabo minima, nihil pariatur, porro possimus rem voluptatem? A dignissimos inventore necessitatibus vel veritatis.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>


    </ul>

    <div class="cd-slider-nav">

      <!--<span class="cd-marker"></span>-->
      <nav>
        <a href="#0" class="selected"></a>
        <a href="#0"></a>
        <a href="#0"></a>
        <a href="#0"></a>
        <a href="#0"></a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- .cd-slider-nav -->
  </section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>



  <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

My problem when I use padding:

[image]

Removing the line `position: fixed;` from   still does not work as it results in:

[image]

Comment: If you want it like the first image, then use `padding-top: 100px;` in `.nav2 ul#menu`

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick fix. Remove position fixed from nav2 class.

```
.nav2 {
  position: fixed; /* remove this line */
  width: 100%;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

I am not sure if the look of the webpage after the removal of position fixed is what you're looking for, but indeed the removal will position the slider below the navbar. This is what you asked for anyway, hence this is my solution.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uo6rxvn/33)

```js
var slidesWrapper = $('.cd-hero-slider');

//check if a .cd-hero-slider exists in the DOM
if (slidesWrapper.length > 0) {

  var sliderNav = $('.cd-slider-nav');
  var slidesNumber = slidesWrapper.children('li').length;
  var visibleSlidePosition = 0;
  var autoPlayId;
  var autoPlayDelay = 5000;

  // autoplay slider
  setAutoplay(slidesWrapper, slidesNumber, autoPlayDelay);

  // change visible slide
  sliderNav.on('click', 'a', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var selectedItem = $(this);

    if (!selectedItem.hasClass('selected')) {

      // if it's not already selected
      var selectedPosition = selectedItem.index();
      var activePosition = slidesWrapper.find('li.selected').index();

      if (activePosition < selectedPosition) {
        nextSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, selectedPosition);
      } else {
        prevSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, selectedPosition);
      }

      //this is used for the autoplay
      visibleSlidePosition = selectedPosition;

      updateSliderNavigation(sliderNav, selectedPosition);
      setAutoplay(slidesWrapper, slidesNumber, autoPlayDelay);
    }
  });
}

function nextSlide(visibleSlide, container, pagination, n) {
  visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
    visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
  });

  container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-right').prevAll().addClass('move-left');
}

function prevSlide(visibleSlide, container, pagination, n) {
  visibleSlide.removeClass('selected from-left from-right').addClass('is-moving').one('webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend', function() {
    visibleSlide.removeClass('is-moving');
  });

  container.children('li').eq(n).addClass('selected from-left').removeClass('move-left').nextAll().removeClass('move-left');
}

function updateSliderNavigation(pagination, n) {
  var navigationDot = pagination.find('.selected');
  navigationDot.removeClass('selected');
  pagination.find('a').eq(n).addClass('selected');
}

// autoplay
function setAutoplay(wrapper, length, delay) {
  if (wrapper.hasClass('autoplay')) {
    clearInterval(autoPlayId);
    autoPlayId = window.setInterval(function() {
      autoplaySlider(length)
    }, delay);
  }
}

function autoplaySlider(length) {
  if (visibleSlidePosition < length - 1) {
    nextSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition + 1);
    visibleSlidePosition += 1;
  } else {
    prevSlide(slidesWrapper.find('.selected'), slidesWrapper, sliderNav, 0);
    visibleSlidePosition = 0;
  }
  updateSliderNavigation(sliderNav, visibleSlidePosition);
}
```

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #2c343b;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

a {
  color: #d44457;
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

.cd-hero {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.03);
}

.cd-hero-slider {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cd-hero-slider li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(100%);
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.cd-hero-slider li.selected {
  /* this is the visible slide */
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.cd-hero-slider li.move-left {
  /* slide hidden on the left */
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected {
  /* the is-moving class is assigned to the slide which is moving outside the viewport */
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.5s;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}


/* --------------------------------

Single slide style

-------------------------------- */

.cd-hero-slider li {
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
  width: 45%;
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width:first-of-type {
  left: 5%;
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width:nth-of-type(2) {
  right: 5%;
  left: auto;
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-content {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(50% - 30px);
  transform: translateY(-52%) !important;
  padding: 0 50px;
}


/*
    animations & transitions
*/

.cd-hero-slider .cd-half-width {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(40px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(40px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(40px);
  -o-transform: translateX(40px);
  transform: translateX(40px);
}

.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-half-width {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-40px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-40px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-40px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-40px);
  transform: translateX(-40px);
}

.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-half-width {
  /* this is the visible slide */
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.cd-hero-slider .is-moving .cd-half-width {
  /* this is the slide moving outside the viewport
    wait for the end of the transition on the <li> parent before set opacity to 0 and translate to 40px/-40px */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0s 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -moz-transform 0s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, transform 0s 0.5s;
}

.cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-left .cd-half-width:nth-of-type(2),
.cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-right .cd-half-width:first-of-type {
  /* this is the selected slide - different animation if it's entering from left or right */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, transform 0.5s 0.2s;
}

.cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-left .cd-half-width:first-of-type,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected.from-right .cd-half-width:nth-of-type(2) {
  /* this is the selected slide - different animation if it's entering from left or right */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.4s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, transform 0.5s 0.4s;
}

.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width h1,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width h2,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width h3,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width h4,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width h5,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width h6,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width p,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width a,
.cd-hero-slider .cd-full-width .button {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(100px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(100px);
  -o-transform: translateX(100px);
  transform: translateX(100px);
}

.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width h1,
.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width h2,
.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width h3,
.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width h4,
.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width h5,
.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width h6,
.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width p,
.cd-hero-slider .move-left .cd-full-width .button {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100px);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100px);
  -o-transform: translateX(-100px);
  transform: translateX(-100px);
}

.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width h1,
.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width h2,
.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width h3,
.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width h4,
.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width h5,
.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width h6,
.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width p,
.cd-hero-slider .selected .cd-full-width .button {
  /* this is the visible slide */
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0);
  -o-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
}

.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width h1,
.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width h2,
.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width h3,
.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width h4,
.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width h5,
.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width h6,
.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width p,
.cd-hero-slider li.is-moving .cd-full-width .button {
  /* this is the slide moving outside the viewport
    wait for the end of the transition on the li parent before set opacity to 0 and translate to 100px/-100px */
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -webkit-transform 0s 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, -moz-transform 0s 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0s 0.5s, transform 0s 0.5s;
}


/* different timings for different elements */

.cd-hero-slider li.selected h1,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected h2,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected h3,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected h4,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected h5,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected h6 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 0.2s, transform 0.5s 0.2s;
}

.cd-hero-slider li.selected p {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.3s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.3s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.3s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 0.3s, transform 0.5s 0.3s;
}

.cd-hero-slider li.selected .button,
.cd-hero-slider li.selected input[type="button"],
.cd-hero-slider li.selected button {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.5s 0.4s, background-color 0.2s 0s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, -moz-transform 0.5s 0.4s, background-color 0.2s 0s;
  transition: opacity 0.4s 0.4s, transform 0.5s 0.4s, background-color 0.2s 0s;
}


/*
    slider navigation
*/

.cd-slider-nav {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  height: 30px;
}

.cd-slider-nav nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.cd-slider-nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.cd-slider-nav a.selected {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}


/* --------------------------------

Javascript disabled

-------------------------------- */

.no-js .cd-hero-slider li {
  display: none;
}

.no-js .cd-hero-slider li.selected {
  display: block;
}

.no-js .cd-slider-nav {
  display: none;
}

@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:400,500,900';
body {
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

.nav2 {
  width: 100%;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-out;
}

.banner {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}

.nav2 ul#menu {
  padding-left: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.nav2 .ul2 .li2 {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.nav-bar {
  /* Rectangle 1: */
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11), 0px 4px 6px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.11);
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------

/*Strip the ul of padding and list styling*/

.ul2 {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
}


/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/

.li2 {
  display: inline-block;
  float: center;
}


/*Style for menu links*/

.li2 .a2 {
  display: block;
  min-width: 140px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  background: #2f3036;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*Hover state for top level links*/

.li2:hover .a2 {
  background: #19c589;
}


/*Style for dropdown links*/

.li2:hover .ul2 .a2 {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  color: #2f3036;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}


/*Hover state for dropdown links*/

.li2:hover .ul2 .a2:hover {
  background: #19c589;
  color: #fff;
}


/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/

.li2 .ul2 {
  display: none;
}


/*Make dropdown links vertical*/

.li2 .ul2 .li2 {
  display: block;
  float: none;
}


/*Prevent text wrapping*/

.li2 .ul2 .li2 .a2 {
  width: auto;
  min-width: 100px;
}


/*Display the dropdown on hover*/

.ul2 .li2 .a2:hover+.hidden,
.hidden:hover {
  display: block;
}


/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/

.show-menu {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  background: #19c589;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
  display: none;
}


/*Hide checkbox*/

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none;
}


/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/

input[type=checkbox]:checked~#menu {
  display: block;
}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
  /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
  .nav2 .ul2#menu {
    position: static;
    display: none;
  }
  /*Create vertical spacing*/
  .li2 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  /*Make all menu links full width*/
  .ul2 .li2,
  .li2 .a2 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  /*Display 'show menu' link*/
  .show-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}

.hero-image {
  /* The image used */
  /* Set a specific height */
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  /* Position and center the image to scale nicely on all screens */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#menu {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>slick slider</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>

  <nav class="nav2">
    <div class="banner animated"><img class="hero-image" src="https://picsum.photos/1080/200/?random"></div>
    <div class="nav-bar"> <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
      <ul id="menu" class="ul2">
        <li class="li2"><a href="#" class="a2">Home</a></li>
        <li class="li2">
          <a href="#" class="a2">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="li2">
          <a href="#" class="a2">Portfolio</a>
        </li>
        <li class="li2"><a href="#" class="a2">News</a></li>
        <li class="li2"><a href="#" class="a2">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <section class="cd-hero">

    <ul class="cd-hero-slider autoplay">

      <li class="selected" style="background-color:#3498db">
        <div class="cd-full-width">
          <div class="cd-content">
            <h2>slide content</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li style="background-color:#34495e">
        <div class="cd-half-width">
          <div class="cd-content">
            <h2>slide content</h2>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cd-half-width cd-img-container">
          <div class="cd-content">
            <h2>slide content</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li style="background-color:#e67e22">
        <div class="cd-half-width cd-img-container">
          <div class="cd-content">
            <h2>slide content</h2>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cd-half-width">
          <div class="cd-content">
            <h2>slide content</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li style="background-color:#2ecc71">
        <div class="cd-full-width">
          <div class="cd-content">
            <h2>slide content</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li style="background-color:#9b59b6">
        <div class="cd-full-width">
          <div class="cd-content">
            <h2>slide content</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut autem commodi corporis, dignissimos dolorem doloremque eveniet explicabo minima, nihil pariatur, porro possimus rem voluptatem? A dignissimos inventore necessitatibus vel veritatis.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>


    </ul>

    <div class="cd-slider-nav">

      <!--<span class="cd-marker"></span>-->
      <nav>
        <a href="#0" class="selected"></a>
        <a href="#0"></a>
        <a href="#0"></a>
        <a href="#0"></a>
        <a href="#0"></a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- .cd-slider-nav -->
  </section>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>



  <script src="js/index.js"></script>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Really? Which browser are you using? I'm on Chrome. Look at this fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/7uo6rxvn/33/

Comment: Weird. It works on my Safari Version 11.1 (13605.1.33.1.2). Have you cleared your broswer cache?

Comment: sorry, there was something wrong with my text editor it has worked thank you! :)

Comment: Good to hear that.