# How to create CSS cards?

Tags: html, css

This question might be a bit broad. I am trying to create three cards and a bar that is on top of them like this:

[image]

Where the orange parts are images and the grey parts are text.

```css
.blue-line {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.card {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-line"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="card"></div>
```

Comment: Feedback: I downvoted this question because (a) this question featured urgent begging until I edited it out, and (b) I [asked you to refrain from this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50896190) before. Remember, things that are urgent for you **are not urgent for anyone else**. It is a rude encroachment on the time of a volunteer to assume otherwise.

Comment: I  am extremely sorry @halfer I promise to refrain from this in the future. Thank you for your constructive criticism!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use FlexBox, like this :

```css
.blue-line {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.card {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-container {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
}

.img {
  height: 100px;
  width:100%;
  background: #febe8c;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-line"></div>
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
      <div class="img">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <div class="img">
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
      <div class="img">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### Containers and items

[image: Container]

[image: Items]

**Initialize flex box**

```
.container {
  display: flex; /* or inline-flex */
}
```

### Order

[image: Order]

```
.item {
  order: <integer>; /* default is 0 */
}
```

### Flex-grow

[image: Flex-grow]

```
.item {
  flex-grow: <number>; /* default 0 */
}
```

---

> Learn more about [Flex Box on css-tricks.com](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

[Sources](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help is there a way to center these cards? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, juste add justify-content: center; in the container

Answer (score 1):

The below code should be okay for you to start with. You can either use an img tag or make the image as a background image(whichever that is okay with you)

```css
.blue-line {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.card {
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: grey;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.card-container {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  display: flex;
}
.img {
  height: 200px;
  width:100%;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="blue-line"></div>
<div class="card-container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img">
    </div>
        <h4>You can input your text here</h4>

  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img">
    </div>
    <h4>You can input your text here</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="img">
    </div>
        <h4>You can input your text here</h4>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}

.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    animation: fadein 1s linear;
}

.item {
    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    flex-basis: 0%;
    background-color: #7e57c2;
    color: white;
    margin: 0.3em;
    /* create shadow */
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.card {
    padding: 1em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

@media all and (max-width: 786px) {
    .card {
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .wrapper {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .item {
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }

}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img src="/assets/insta.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h3>Card Title</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, quidem.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img src="/assets/insta.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h3>Card Title</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, quidem.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-image">
                        <img src="/assets/insta.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <h3>Card Title</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quisquam, quidem.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```